# huge gap above div while positioning ontop of another div

Tags: html, css

I have managed to position div on top of another div however I do not know why I am getting the gap ontop.

see screenshot:
[image: between cloudy sky above and bottom blue part]
between cloudy sky above and bottom blue part.

Here is the css:

```
/*
 * Hero section 
 */

.hero-section .section-content {
  position: relative;
  top: 70px;
}

.hero-section .section-content h2 {
  font-size: 30px;
}

.hero-section .section-content .btn-primary {
  margin-right: 1px;
}
.sunny {
  width:200px; /*width of your image*/
   height:200px; /*height of your image*/
   background: transparent url("img/sunny.png") bottom right no-repeat;
   border: 2px solid #000;
   margin:0; /* If you want no margin */
   padding:0; /*if your want to padding */
}

.weather-icon-pos{
    display: inline-block;
    position:relative;
    top:95px;
    width:75%;
  }
```

see [full code on GitHub](https://github.com/sanfx/WeatherApp/blob/master/templates/index.html#L9)

any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** Check the Fiddle below for basic image overlay behavior.

**Generic image overlay example:**

```css
.bottom {
  width: 100%;
  height: 52px;
}
.top {
  border: 1px solid red;
  position: absolute;
  top: 8px;
  right: 8px;
}
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/200x200" alt="" class="bottom">
<img src="https://placehold.it/50x50" alt="" class="top">
```

---

**Original Answer**

You can workaround it by removing `position:relative` from `section-content`, but wouldn't know about the rest of the layout.

Whats causing it is these 2 `top` coordinates:

- `.weather-icon-pos` - `top: 95px;`
- `.hero-section .section-content` - `top: 70px;`

If you comment them you will see the black rectangle stack up.

[image]

Comment: if I comment out `top:95px;` then I won't be able to align image ontop of other image

Comment: Hard to say without the actual working code, ideally you would place the image above with z-index, not the whole container (if its including child elements). Maybe you can come up with a simpler fiddle? Have you tried removing section-content coordinates and tweaking from there the icon one?

Comment: I have given link of my GitHub in the opening post. can you help me that way,

Comment: Ciasto, was the first thing I checked my friend, it's worthless without proper dev environment, also there is tons of irrelevant code. I will add above a basic example that hopefully you will be able to apply to your work.

Comment: Ciasto, you can also remove position:relative from section-content, see if that helps you. It's what's causing the weather-icon coordinates to stick to it's parent relative coordinates.

Comment: thanks the example you will post will be helpful, I am looking forward how can I take advantage of `z-index`, I have removed section content and position relative.